# How to define a constraint TimeFold for Staff scheduling if schedules are define in slot

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I'm attempting to recreate the functionality of the TimeFold example found at https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/employee-scheduling. In my scenario, the availability of employees includes both start and end dates, not just a single date. How should I define the `unavailableEmployee` constraints to ensure that if an employee's availability period falls within a shift, the availability score is adjusted accordingly based on availability type.

This is what is in example

```
Constraint unavailableEmployee(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Shift.class)
            .join(Availability.class, Joiners.equal((Shift shift) -> shift.getStart().toLocalDate(), Availability::getDate),
                    Joiners.equal(Shift::getEmployee, Availability::getEmployee))
            .filter((shift, availability) -> availability.getAvailabilityType() == AvailabilityType.UNAVAILABLE)
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    (shift, availability) -> getShiftDurationInMinutes(shift))
            .asConstraint("Unavailable employee");
}
```

But as you see in this example only start date is compared but in my case I need to check if shift falls inside availability range. What is the correct way of solving this problem.

Comment: Take a look at `Joiners.overlapping()` in the docs.

Comment: I tried this `constraintFactory.forEach(Shift.class).join(Availability.class, Joiners.equal(Shift::getProvider, Availability::getProvider), Joiners.overlapping(Availability::getStart, Shift::getStart, Availability::getEnd, Shift::getEnd))` but its not working.

Comment: It's (start1, end1, start2, end2), not (start1, start2, end1, end2). What you have there shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Thank you its working now. However, it is still giving match even if HardConstraints are violated. Is there a way to not get result if HardConstraints are violated.

Comment: You can use a "feasible termination", to keep solving, but typically want to combine that with a time spend termination in case there is no feasible solution.
Even then you'd need to do `if (!solution.getScore().isFeasible())` to see if hard constraints are broken.

Comment: What you typically want to do is overconstrained planning. Don't require all entities to be assigned, through nullable=true and a medium constraint than penalizes the number of unassigned entities. See docs on overconstrained planning.